# Sort Options are not populated in the inbuilt filtering for jqgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, jqgrid

I am using Jqgrid grid in my asp.net web application. I wanted to use inbuilt filtering .

But, the problem is that even though i have included sort options. they are not coming up in the dropdown list in the Search popup.

Here is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Data").jqGrid({
                url: '/Home/LoadData',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "GET",
                colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "Col1", width: 70, align: "left", sortable: false, search: false },
                    { name: "Col2", index: 'Col2', width: 140, align: "left", sortable: true, stype: 'text' },
                    { name: "Col3", index: 'Col3', width: 160, align: "left", sortable: true, search: true },

                          ],
                pager: "#Pager",
                rowNum: '10',
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                sortname: "Col1",
                sortorder: "asc",
                searchGrid: "options",
                height: "auto",
                gridview: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Sample Demo Grid"
            }).navGrid('#Pager',
    {
        view: false,
        del: false,
        search: true,
        refresh: true,
        add: false,
        edit: false
    },
        {
            sopt: ['cn', 'nc', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'bn', 'in', 'ni', 'ew', 'en']
        }
    );
        });
```

Please help..Those sort options are not coming up in dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the 3-th parameter of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) to specify object with `sopt` property. The 3-th parameter is `prmEdit` and can be used to customize Edit form. You can use 6-th option (`prmSearch`) of `navGrid` to customize searching options:

```js
$("#Data").jqGrid("navGrid", "#Pager",
    { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, 
    {}, {}, {},
    { sopt: [ ... ]}
);
```

Alternatively you can first changed default options `$.jgrid.search` used by searching (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7275732/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10062849/315935) for code example) and then use short call of `navGrid` (`$("#Data").jqGrid("navGrid", "#Pager", { del: false, add: false, edit: false });`).

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, here i am loading data page by page not all at a time.so, do i need to do server side filtering inorder to get the correct results right?

Comment: @Avinash: If you implemented *server side paging* then you should implement server side filtering too (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) for code examples)

Comment: @Oleg..can you please help me on this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405975/how-to-do-external-filtering-on-jqgrid

Comment: @Oleg..can you please help me on this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420373/how-to-display-indirect-data-in-jqgrid

Comment: @Avinash: I'v seen your question and I find it interesting, so I'll answer on it later. I have to do my main job and I can't spend my whole time in answering questions on stackoverflow. :-)

Comment: @Avinash: I found now time to answer your question. After thinking about the problem I suggested many variation which could be helpful you and other readers.