# How to do external filtering on jqgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, filtering

I am implementing jqGrid in my ASP.net web aplication, and I don't want to use the inbuilt filtering provided by jqGrid. So, I thought of using external filtering.

I will have a textbox. As soon as a user enters a value and clicks on the button filter, I would like to reload the grid. I am using server side pagination and I must do server side filtering.

I have some posts regarding this, but I was not able to find a solid example to demonstrate this.

I also dont know how the filter value is recieved in the C# code to do the filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `postData` parameter in jQGrid and pass your own values to filter and refresh grid

```
$(document).ready(SearchPatients);
```

and

```
function SearchPatients() {
    'use strict';
    jQuery("#patient-search-grid").jqGrid({
    url: '/Patient/Search/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    postData: { ID:function(){return $("#txtbkgID").val();} },
    //postData:{search:function () { return getSearchPostData() } }, 
    colNames: [{'Id','Pid','FullName'}],
    colModel: [
               { name: 'Id', index: 'Id',hidden: true },
               { name: 'PatientIdentifier',index: 'PatientIdentifier'},
               { name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName'}
             ],
    height: "100%",
    pager: '#patient-search-pager',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 30, 50],
    sortname: 'Id',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "Search Results"

  }

function getSearchPostData(){
 var searchData = {};
 searchData.PatientIdentifier = $('#patient-identifier').val();
 searchData.FirstName = $('#first-name').val();
 searchData.LastName = $('#last-name').val();   
 return JSON.stringify(searchData);
}
```

In Controller add optional parameter ID

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Search(string ID)
    {
      //Request.Params["ID"] also will work

    }
```

Comment: @Murali..i would like to pass only one filter criteria..can i use the folowing syntax:

    postData:
                {
                   ID:function(){return $("#txtbkgID").val();}
                },

Comment: @Murali..How to trigger grid reload on button click

Comment: @Avinash, yes you can. Not a problem. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Avinash, `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");`

Comment: Thanks Murali.How to recieve that PostData in the c# code. Since, the same url is used for the intial load of data and reloading.

Comment: @Avinash, you are welcome. Hope I reduced Oleg's burden today :)

Comment: @Murali..really. he has been answering a lot questions of mine..:)

Comment: @Murali..do you have any example containing all the information about jqgrid

Comment: @Avinash, Yes. He is always great person. He was helped me a lot before :)

Comment: @Murali..when ever there is time for you..can you please look into my questions in the coming days..i started working on MVC and there are not many persons who answer on jqgrid and MVC related stuffs.that would be of lot of help to me..

Comment: @Avinash, there is some demo link setup at [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html‎) and some thing [here](http://jqgrid.com/)

Comment: @Murali..Thanks i will look into that link.